# Altering a Jquery Drop Down Filter Plugin to Refocus on the Dropdown after applying the Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

The Plugin I'm using is direct from the Jquery site, Source Pastebin'd Here http://pastebin.com/RRr6EJhv

When the Filter is applied to the Select Box in Question I'd like focus to return to the drop down because the plugin automatically selects the first of the filtered records and I have an Onchange event on the drop down which isn't being triggered, so I can add an Onfocus event to trigger the same function and this will respond to the focus() command.

I tried adding document.getElementById('PATIENT').focus(); to the bottom of this plugin file and above the "Return true" but neither worked, both said that document.getElementById('PATIENT') was null.

thanks!

EDIT:

Thanks to the people who were helpful, as I dug further into this Plugin's documentation I discovered some cross Browser problems and some other bugs and issues, So instead of Modifying this one, I switched to another plugin that does Similar things, it can be found here: http://vladimir-k.blogspot.com/2009/02/sexy-combo-jquery-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting `null`, the element may not exist yet. You should call this inside a `document.ready(function(){})` So do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  ...
  var id =document.getElementById('PATIENT');
  ...
});
```

If this doesn't work, it means you don't have an element with `id="PATIENT"`

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: The issue I'm having is after the filter is applied to the contents of the drop down, so the page isn't reloaded (which is when document.ready fires I thought?). The Element is on the page, so it exists, the plguin is in another file, which is read in at the head, is that causing the issues?

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the this.priv_df.DoFilter function, try adding

```
$(thisDF).focus();
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Ninja edit to change thisDF.focus() to $(thisDF).focus(); because it has to be a jQuery object...